# Can I stay in France using a Carte de Séjour Travailleur Saisonnier even when I am not working?

Tags: working-visas, france, resident-permit

I have lived in France using a season visa for 6 months now and before that I lived in France using a working holiday visa for one year.. my seasonal visa has almost expired. But I have received my carte de séjour recently and it doesn't expire until 2020. Does that mean I can continue to live and work in France using my carte de séjour once my original seasonal visa has expired? The specific carte is carte de séjour "travailleur saisonnier" i understand that means I can only work six months per year. But does that mean six months starting in January or starting of the original visa? Or start of the carte de séjour? Also can I stay in France during the time I'm not working using the carte de séjour?

Comment: Yes, it would seem so, what's the “mention”/on what basis did you apply for a carte de séjour?

Comment: It's a "travailleur saisonnier" carte de séjour. They gave the card to me after my visa had expired without explanation of the card.. i know with this card I can work 6 months per year. But it does not define if it's 6 months starting from January or starting from the original visa or from when I received the card. The card is valid until 2020 but does that mean I can stay in France during the period I'm not aloud to work?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm qualified to turn this into an answer, but check [this French government site](http://www.immigration.interieur.gouv.fr/Archives/Les-archives-du-site/Archives-Immigration/Archives-Immigration-professionnelle/La-carte-de-sejour-portant-la-mention-travailleur-saisonnier). Based on Google translation, it states that your residence must not be in France.

Comment: @Brandon It seems to be a rolling 12-month period. You are not allowed to stay in France, you even have to prove you went back to your usual place of residence by showing your passport at the border (“*À l’issue de la période d’emploi en France, les ressortissants étrangers font contrôler leur passeport à la sortie du territoire pour attester de leur retour dans leur pays*”).

Comment: Oh really? That's extremely strange. I exited France and travelled to another country out side the EU for a holiday and returned as a tourist and the had no problems at the boarders note did I get my passport checked when I left. Well I'll continue to contact prefectures to make sure I'm doing the correct thing .. well thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Brandon I would not expect any problems with a two-week holiday now, it's not leaving or coming and going that's forbidden, it's staying permanently. The question is what happens after 1 or 2 years on that card and especially when you try to renew it. You need to be able to show you have been out of France half the time.